# How to delete multiple elements from a array at the same time

Tags: c, arrays

I want to delete multiple elements from array using index array,this is my code:

```
// b is an index array, n is size of b,
// player is the array need to be delete elements,
// size is the size of player
void play_cards(int b[],int n,int player[],int *size){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete_cards(b[i],player,size);
}

void delete_cards(int n,int player[],int *size){
    int i;
    for(i = n; i < *size; i++)
        player[i] = player[i+1];   
    *size -= 1;
}

int main(void){

  int player[10] = {1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7};
  int index[6] = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
  int size = 10;

  play_cards(index,6,player,&size);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       printf("%d|",player[i]);
  puts("");

  return 0;
}
```

I expect print the player should be 1,2,6,7 instead of 1,2,3,4. How should I fix it?

Comment: To remove from the end of the (big) index.  `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)` --> `for(i = n-1; i >=0; --i)`

Comment: which print? I don't see it

Comment: The problem is that once you've removed card at index 2, the meaning of index 3 has changed; what was originally at 3 is now at 2.  You're going to need to think rather carefully about how to resolve this.  And if the contents of the `index` array is not guaranteed to be sorted, it won't help if you work from the tail of the list of indexes (but if the indexes are guaranteed to be in ascending order, it will work). Are the elements of `index` guaranteed to be unique? (It is problematic in most card games if you play the same card twice, so the answer to that's probably "Yes — they're unique".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would not call the function `delete_cards` as it suggests that it deletes multiple cards which it does not - just `delete_card` would make things more clear.

Anyway - when you change the `player` array before you have played all cards in the `index` array, you change the meaning of the indexes. This is why your current code doesn't work.

So you can do two things:

a) Play *all* cards first and then delete the cards played. This could be done by first marking played card with `-1` and then have a loop where you removed all element being `-1`

or

b) Play a card, delete it and adjust the remaining elements in `index` by decrementing them by one. Note: This solution requires that `index` is sorted (lowest first).

Solution a) could look something like this:

```
void delete_played_cards(int player[],int *size)
{
    int i;
    int next_pos = 0;
    int deleted = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < *size; i++)
    {
        if (player[i] != -1)
        {
            player[next_pos] = player[i];
            if (i != next_pos)
            {
                player[i] = -1;
            }
            ++next_pos;
        }
        else
        {
            ++deleted;
        }
    }

    *size -= deleted;
}

void play_cards(int b[],int n,int player[],int *size)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        player[b[i]] = -1;  // Mark card as played
    }

    delete_played_cards(player,size);
}

int main(void)
{
  int player[10] = {1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7};
  int index[6] = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
  int size = 10;

  play_cards(index,6,player,&size);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       printf("%d|",player[i]);
  puts("");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify `play_cards`:

```c
void play_cards(int b[], int n, int player[], int *size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
        delete_cards(b[i],player,size);
}
```

This will start deleting from the end of array.
As [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

here is a pseudocode that you can work with:

```
given a sorted list, 1..n

for i = 2 up to length of list:
  if list[i] is equal to list[i-1]:
    shift the sublist [2..] 1 position to the left
  else
     increment i by 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete easily and efficiently without using loop you can use `memcpy`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INDEX_MAX 6

int main ()
{
   int size = 10;
   int src[] = {1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7};
   int index[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
   int x;

   size = size - INDEX_MAX; 
   memcpy(src+2, src+8, sizeof(int)*(size-2));// - 2 since index 1 and 2 remains in the array

   for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
       printf("%d",src[x]);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants to do. OP wants to fill an `index` array with th e cards to be played, call the `play_cards`function and have the `player` array reorganized.

Comment: You dont' want `sizeof(int)*(size-2)`. You access out of bounds.